# Right shift with bitwise AND

Tags: c, bit

A solution from a [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c-c#answer-47990) is

> To check a bit, shift the number x to the right, then bitwise AND it:
>
> `bit = (number >> x) & 1;`
>
> That will put the value of bit x into the variable bit.

What confuses me is this, when assuming the following:

```
unsigned number = 5; //0101
int x = 2; //
```

After a shift `(number >> x)` we get `0001`. But we shifted off bits 1 and 2 and so when we do the **bitwise AND**, aren't we doing it against the *third* bit and not the *second*, where `x = 2`? Doesn't this mean that if I want to check if bit `x` is set, shouldn't I do:

```
 bit = (number >> (x - 1)) & 1);
```

Comment: I think we are doing it against the 3rd bit from the right, since we took out 2 bits and now we're at the 3rd.

Comment: "bit n" is the (n + 1)th bit.

Comment: Consider checking against the first bit ... there would be no need to shift, hence when you shift n bits, you will check against bit n+1.

Comment: I'd normally say "bit N" or "the Nth bit counting from zero" to hopefully avoid confusion!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you are doing the bitwise AND against the third bit. Consider `x` to be zero-indexed, i.e. the first bit is bit 0.

Comment: Ah okay. I knew that we started bit indexes at `x_i : i = 0` but I didn't know that when we say "Check the second bit" in English, we actually mean check bit `x_2` where this is truly the third bit in the list

Comment: Sorry for the additional question: so if I'm trying to check some bit flag in a register and the documentation says, "check if the 5th bit is set for this feature", do I do `(feature >> 5) & 1` or `(feature >> 4) & 1` ?

Comment: Exactly: the second bit is bit 1... It is can be even more confusing because some people number bits from the most significant to the least significant, because that's how they appear left to right on a chart.

Comment: @8protons: *check if the 5th bit is set for this feature*: such wording is inherently imprecise.  Look at diagrams to see how bits are numbered, hardware people usually number them from most significant to least significant, 1-based.

Comment: That's not consistent

Comment: @kdopen: I agree it is not, it is not the most common choice, but is not unusual and seems more common on big-endian architectures.

Answer (score 2):

You said:

> After a shift `(number >> x)` we get `0001`. But we shifted off bits 1 and 2 and so when we do the **bitwise AND**, aren't we doing it against the *third* bit and not the *second*, where `x = 2`? Doesn't this mean that if I want to check if bit `x` is set, shouldn't I do:
>
> ```
> bit = (number >> (x - 1)) & 1);
> ```

To get the value of the 1st least significant bit, you need `(number >> 0) & 1`.
To get the value of the 2nd least significant bit, you need `(number >> 1) & 1`.
To get the value of the 3rd least significant bit, you need `(number >> 2) & 1`.

etc.

In other words,

1st implies 0 bits to shift
2nd implies 1 bits to shift
3rd implies 2 bits to shift
Nth implies N-1 bits to shift

I hope that makes it a little bit clearer for you.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I'm basically been hung up on this small detail because I'm trying to check a register for a certain CPU feature (if it's enabled or not). The Wiki doc says, " If supported, bit 30 of the ECX register is set". So I wasn't sure if I should be doing `(ECX >> 30) & 1` or `(ECX >> 29) & 1`

Comment: @8protons, I think `((ECX >> 29) & 1` will the right thing.

Comment: My bad. I reread the Intel manual and it starts from bit **00**, thus bit **30** is really the 31st bit and thus ((ECX >> 30) & 1) would work! Thank you

Comment: @8protons, I am glad you figured out the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The bit number represents the power of two. Thus when `x` is two, you are talking about bit 2 = 2**2 = 4.

The least-significant bit (or 'right most' bit if you prefer it bit 0, not bit 1.

Also, there is no reason to actually do the bit shift unless your 'bit number' is in a variable.

For example, to test bit 5 of a value, simply do

```
if (variable & 0x20)
    bit_is_set();
```

Here `0x20` is simply 2**5, (or 1 << 5)

Comment: What is confusing about the words "power of two"? For a programmer?